# What happens when loading a struct with an array to an SSBO?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, buffer, gpu

I have taken the following SSBO declaration from the Khronos wiki:

```
struct ssbo_data_t
{
    int foo;
    float bar[42];
    float baz[MY_SIZE];
} ssbo_data;
```

This data structure has two arrays, one of fixed length one of variable length.

The same declaration on the CPP side would be identical, but to be precise about how the memory is actually structured I will declare it slightly differently:

```
struct ssbo_data_t
{
    int foo;
    float bar*;
    float baz*;
} ssbo_data;
```

In other words, in the CPP side this data structure occupies three different sections, the struct and the 2 arrays. The fields in the struct merely being pointers to the arrays, which looks more or less like this:

[image]

However my expectation is that the SSBO data needs to look as follows in order to be passed to the shader:

[image]

Thus it is my expectation that if one attempts to naively upload the CPP texture to the SSBO, we will get an error, since we are not uploading all the data, but simply the integer and the 2 pointers followed by a lot of memory that is very unlikely to be the data we want (assuming no segmentation fault occurred).

Is this explanation correct? Or does OpenGL have a way to identify pointers and load their data appropriately into the shaders?

If I am completly mistaken please explain how the SSBO is actually loaded in these cases.

Comment: "*I have taken the following SSBO declaration from the Khronos wiki:*" That's the C++ declaration, *not* the GLSL one. The GLSL one is right above that.

Comment: I need a varying size array for the C++ structure, and I beleive this will make it so that the memory will not be contiguous. And I need contiguous memory for this to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, in the CPP side this data structure occupies three different sections, the struct and the 2 arrays.

No, it does not. Arrays and pointers are *not the same thing*. `sizeof(int[20])` is equivalent to `sizeof(int) * 20`. Whereas `sizeof(int*)` is not equivalent to `sizeof(int[20])` or `sizeof(int) * 20`.

Array members of data structures take up storage in-situ, just like any other member suboboject.

Comment: I do not understand, for the variable size array don't you allocate it's emmory using malloc? (I have not used plain C in a while so I forget)

Comment: Also it is valid in C to re-allocate the size of either of the two arrays isn't it?

Comment: I beleive my question was poorly asked and wish to delete it. However you have put in the efforth to answer so I request your permission. If you refuse I'll accept your answer.